# Converting Markdown to HTML

Tags: html, node.js, markdown

I am creating a website. I am using Node.JS, Express and MongoDB

This is the schema that I designed for my website

```
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    paper: String,
    content: String
})
```

[image]

If I click the "Submit" button, the data is well inserted into the DB.
However, when I click the post. This is what I see

[image]

Here is my code.

```
  <div class="container">
    <h1> <%= review.title%></h1>
    <h3> <%= review.author %> - <%= review.paper %></h3>
    <a role="button" class="addbutton btn btn-default btn-info" href="<%=review._id%>/edit" style="margin-left: 0px;">Edit</a>
    <form action="/reviews/<%=review._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <button class="addbutton btn btn-default btn-danger" style="margin-left: 0px">Delete</button>
    </form>
    <hr>

    <p> <%= review.content %> </p>
</div>


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pagedown/1.0/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>

<script>
    var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
    editor.run();
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried <%- review.content %> . It prints <br> tag correctly but the bold text is not working

Comment: `**` isn't html.  That can't just be put in HTML.

Comment: @DanFarrell So I need to add MarkDown converter. right?

Answer (score 0):

need to download markdown converter
and use
makrdown.toHTML()